# Wrong alignment or "floating" comment?

Tags: bug, comments

It is probably a minor issue, but I thought I should still bring it to the attention of the community...  [Jan's comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85835/why-overlapping-area-of-atomic-orbitals-increase-bond-strength#comment153974_85835) is a bit "off"

[image: screenshot demonstrating the wrong alignment]

Am I the only one seeing it?

Comment: **I can confirm the odd behaviour** (Chrome 61.0.3163.100).// Mod-specific: When I display deleted comments, the alignment issue is no longer present.

Comment: Can also confirm (using Safari, probably current version). I knew my comments are always a bit off …

Comment: The SE style sheet *should* include a `.comment-actions { width: 15px }` rule that prevents the left column (with the score and the flag / upvote icons)  from expanding wider than that, even if there's room for it to do so. If I manually disable that rule in Chrome / Firefox developer console, I see exactly what your screenshot shows. The only question is why you're seeing that *without* (presumably) messing with the site CSS.